# Flutter Notifications after one hour

Tags: flutter, notifications

Hello I need to make local notification on mobile whenever a button is pressed. And i don't want to make the notification instantly but after one hour when the user hit that button does anyone have any idea?

I tried this plugin `flutter_local_notifications: ^8.2.0`

But can some help me how to do the trigger after one hour

Thanks

Comment: You can search for "scheduled" here https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: I recommend checking this video out from the Flutter team https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQBpOIHE4eE

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to call notifications every hour

```
 shownotifications() async {

const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails('repeating channel id',
        'repeating channel name', 'repeating description');
const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().periodicallyShow(0, 'Test title',
    'test body', RepeatInterval.hourly, platformChannelSpecifics,
    androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
 }
```

and follow this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/local-notifications-in-flutter/) step by step to to setup the package you are using

Comment: can this be scheduled after one hour after the user clicks a button?

Comment: yes and check i have made an edit